# $f\otimes 1$ is integral if $f$ is

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, modules

Suppose that $f:B\to B'$ is an integral homomorphism of $A$-algebras, and let $C$ be an $A$-algebra. Show that $f\otimes_A1_C$ is an integral homomorphism.

Take $x\otimes c\in B'\otimes_AC$: $$\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb N}(B\otimes_AC)\cdot(x\otimes c)^n\cong$$ $$ \bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb N}((B\cdot x^n)\otimes_A(C\cdot c^n))\subseteq$$ $$(\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb N}(B\cdot x^n))\otimes_AC\cong B[x]\otimes_AC.$$ *The last one is a subring of $B'\otimes_AC$, and it is finitely generated as a module over $B\otimes_AC$*: in fact $x$ being integral over $B$ is equivalent to $B[x]$ being a finitely generated $B$-module (say by $y_1,\dots, y_r)$; thus the $y_1\otimes 1,\dots, y_r\otimes 1$ generate $B[x]\otimes_AC$. The thesis should follow directly from the observation in *italics* (theorem 5.1, Atiyah-Macdonald).

Does this proof work? On a paper I found a slightly different one, and I don't understand if it's just a matter of taste or it's because mine is flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easier and direct proof. Let $b' \otimes c \in B' \otimes_A C$. We want to find a monic polynomial with coefficients in $(f \otimes_A 1_C)(B \otimes_A C)$ that $b' \otimes c$ satisfies. Since $f$ is an integral homomorphism, we can find $b_0, \cdots, b_{n-1} \in B$ such that
$$(b')^n + f(b_{n-1}) (b')^{n-1} + \cdots + f(b_0) = 0$$
Then it is evident that $b' \otimes c$ satisfies
$$(b' \otimes c)^n + (f(b_{n-1}) \otimes c) (b' \otimes c)^{n-1} + \cdots + (f(b_0) \otimes c^n) = 0$$
You can easily check that every coefficient is in $(f \otimes_A 1_C)(B \otimes C)$, so the map $f \otimes_A 1_C$ is integral.